# How to stringify an object of the type Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class test{
    name : string
    children : Map<string,string> =new Map()
    constructor(){
        this.name='KIANA'
        this.children.set('name','OTTO')
    }
}
var t = new test()
console.log(t)
console.log(JSON.stringify(t))
```

The result is:

```
test { children: Map { 'name' => 'OTTO' }, name: 'KIANA' }
{"children":{},"name":"KIANA"}
```

How can I get the whole data like:

```
{"children":{'name':'OTTO'},"name":"KIANA"}
```

or

```
{"children":['name':'OTTO'],"name":"KIANA"}
```

Or, does it has a simpler way to describe the relationship of 'key value' in JSON and TypeScript

Comment: convert thr map to an object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preface: Class names should start with an uppercase character, so I've changed `test` to `Test` in the below.

Since `Map` isn't stringify-able by default, you have at least three choices:

1. Implement `toJSON` on your `Test` class and return an object with a replacement for `children` (probably an array of arrays), or
2. Implement a subclass of `Map` that has `toJSON` and use that in `Test`
3. Implement a *replacer* that you use with `JSON.stringify` that handles `Map` instances.

While #1 works, it means you have to edit your `toJSON` method every time you add or remove properties from `Test`, which seems like a maintenance issue:

```
class Test {
  name: string
  children: Map<string, string> = new Map()
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'KIANA'
    this.children.set('name', 'OTTO')
  }
  toJSON() {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      children: [...this.children.entries()]
    }
  }
}
var t = new Test()
console.log(JSON.stringify(t))
```

Live Example:

```js
class Test {
  name/*: string*/
  children/*: Map<string, string>*/ = new Map()
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'KIANA'
    this.children.set('name', 'OTTO')
  }
  toJSON() {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      children: [...this.children.entries()]
    }
  }
}
var t = new Test()
console.log(JSON.stringify(t))
```

`[...this.children.entries()]` creates an array of `[name, value]` arrays for the map.

But I prefer #2, a JSON-compatible `Map`:

```
class JSONAbleMap extends Map {
  toJSON() {
    return [...this.entries()]
  }
}
```

...which you then use in `Test`:

```
class Test {
  name: string
  children: Map<string, string> = new JSONAbleMap()
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'KIANA'
    this.children.set('name', 'OTTO')
  }
}
var t = new Test()
console.log(JSON.stringify(t))
```

Live Example:

```js
class JSONAbleMap extends Map {
  toJSON() {
    return [...this.entries()]
  }
}

class Test {
  name/*: string*/
  children/*: Map<string, string>*/ = new JSONAbleMap()
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'KIANA'
    this.children.set('name', 'OTTO')
  }
}
var t = new Test()
console.log(JSON.stringify(t))
```

Or #3, a replacer function you use with `JSON.stringify`:

```
function mapAwareReplacer(key: string|Symbol, value: any): any {
    if (value instanceof Map && typeof value.toJSON !== "function") {
        return [...value.entries()]
    }
    return value
}
```

...which you use when calling `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(t, mapAwareReplacer))
```

Live Example:

```js
function mapAwareReplacer(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Map && typeof value.toJSON !== "function") {
        return [...value.entries()]
    }
    return value
}

class Test {
  name/*: string*/
  children/*: Map<string, string>*/ = new Map()
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'KIANA'
    this.children.set('name', 'OTTO')
  }
}
var t = new Test()
console.log(JSON.stringify(t, mapAwareReplacer))
```